# RegularExpressionValidator returns false for valid input

Tags: c#, regex, validation, c#-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to validate time zone offset which has the format of optional minus sign, followed by two digits, followed by colon followed by two more digits; like -05:00 or 04:30.
I used \b[-]?\d{2}:\d{2}\b as validation expression, tested it on some online RE testing sites and I get "Successful Match" but validator keeps returning falase. I can't see what I am doing wrong. I enter -05:00 or -13:99 and they both return false. I tried to escape the colon but same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the word boundaries then you'll get your matches.

```
-?\d{2}:\d{2}
```

If you only want the first occurrence then make it like this:

```
-?\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

If you only want to match valid times use this one:

```
-?([0-2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])
```

The above one matches any hour in the range of 0-23:0-59 btw.